# Nodes that point to panel pages

Tags: panels

I'm having an issue with deciding how to display nodes that in turn point to panel pages.

My site currently has a lot of panel pages that have static content. I have a view on my front page that displays nodes which in turn point to these panel pages. However, when a user clicks on a node link, they'll of course see the node in isolation.

In order for me to point users to the correct page, I've been using redirects. So if a user clicks on featured article on the home page,  a redirect pushes them to the panel page I've set up instead of just the node view.

Have I made this overly complicated? Is there a way to making this workflow a lot simpler?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the node override panel page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MPD was correct. I had neglected to use the node override panel page correctly. Thank you!